# If $f(x) = 2x(2-x)\;,$ Where $0\leq x\leq 1$. Then no. of real solution of $ f(f(f(f(x))))=\frac{x}{3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $f(x) = 2x(2-x)\;,$ Where $0\leq x\leq 1$. Then no. of real solution of $f(f(x))=0$
>
> and $f(f(f(x)))=0$ and $\displaystyle f(f(f(f(x))))=\frac{x}{3}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ Let $$y=2x(2-x)$$ and given $$0\leq x \leq 1.$$ and  Graph  of $$y=2x(2-x)$$

is an downward parabola Whose Minimum value is $y=0$ at $x=0$ and Maximum value is

$y=2$ at $x=1$. So we get $0\leq y\leq 2$.

Now $$f(f(x))=0\Rightarrow 2f(x)\cdot \left\{2-f(x)\right\}=0\Rightarrow 2f(x)\cdot \left\{2-f(x)\right\}=0$$

So either $$f(x)=0\Rightarrow 2x(2-x)=0\Rightarrow x = 0\;,x=2$$ or

either $$f(x)=2\Rightarrow 2x(2-x)=2\Rightarrow x(2-x)=1\Rightarrow (x-1)^2=0$$

So we get two repeated roots which is $x=1$ and $x=1$ bcz $f(f(x))=0$ is a fourth degree

polynomial. So roots of $$f(f(x))=0$$ are $$x=0\;,1\;,1\;,2$$.

Now How can I solve for questions $f(f(f(x)))=0$ and  $\displaystyle f(f(f(f(x))))=\frac{x}{3}$

help me Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're well on your way to solving this one, I get the feeling that you're a bit hesitant to try applying the same technique to the next step because it could get ugly. And it does to an extent, but not to despair, because it works out quite neatly.

For the $\ f(f(f(x)))=0$ case, we can write $\ 2f(f(x))*(2-f(f(x)))=0$ which has solutions $\ f(f(x))=0$ and $\ f(f(x))=2$, the first of which you (conveniently) have already worked out.

To get the second solution we have to solve $\ 2f(x)*(2-f(x))=2$, which isn't as straight forward as the first solution, but really isn't that tricky.

$$
\ f(x)*(2-f(x))=1\\
\ (f(x))^2-2f(x)+1=0\\
\ (f(x)-1)*(f(x)-1)=0\\
$$
(Please ask if I've jumped too many steps here)

So for the second solution, we have the repeated roots $f(x)=1$, which should be trivial to solve.

Give this a go and see where it takes you. I haven't solved the full question myself, but I would take note that a key phrase in the question is "real" solutions.

Good Luck!